# Excel VBA add data validation with date less or equal to dynamic todays date

Tags: excel, vba, validation

As in the title Im trying to add data validation with date less or equal than todays date. By todays date I refer to dynamically check for date when sheet is edited. Below is my code:

```
            With Selection.Validation
                .Delete
                .Add Type:=xlValidateDate, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlLessEqual, Formula1:="=NOW()"
                .ErrorMessage = "Wprowadź datę w formacie dd.mm.rrrr"
            End With
```

I get here runtime 1004 error with this line:

```
.Add Type:=xlValidateDate, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlLessEqual, Formula1:="=NOW()"
```

I've been trying to use `=TODAY` insted of `=NOW` but output was the same.

Comment: Nothing wrong with that line of code & it works for me. Must be something else - what is selected when the code runs? Try specifying a cell rather than `selection`.

Comment: Ech... The problem was caused by some protected sheets in my workbook. Sorry for wasting your time, but thanks for the comment. It helped me to figure it out!

Answer (score 0):

The code works fine but some sheets in my workbook were protected. When I unprotected them code worked perfectly.